# python - hmac new sha1

Tags: python, python-2.7, sha1, hmac

I am trying to get the same result as [this online API service produces](https://developertools.esd.org.uk/service?organisations/barrowbc).

By entering `key` as the application key, and `secret` as the secret produces the following URL:

```
http://webservices.esd.org.uk/organisations/barrowbc?ApplicationKey=key&Signature=YXWJsGSKnLcENW1vm30EYObbCsA=
```

I have tried producing the same signature using the following code:

```
import hmac    
import urllib
import base64
from hashlib import sha1


def sign_url(url,key,secret):
    url = url + 'ApplicationKey=' + key
    signature = hmac.new(secret,url,sha1).digest().encode("base64") 
    signature = '&Signature=' + signature
    url = url + signature
    print(url)

sign_url('http://webservices.esd.org.uk/organisations/barrowbc','key','secret')
```

but this produces:

```
http://webservices.esd.org.uk/organisations/barrowbcApplicationKey=key&Signature=W//jgV+xdSbTBG6+i1TCGN/Kbsk=
```

The expected signature is

```
YXWJsGSKnLcENW1vm30EYObbCsA=
```

but my code outputs

```
W//jgV+xdSbTBG6+i1TCGN/Kbsk=
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on what inputs, exactly, the signature must be based on?

Comment: there is this:
https://api.esd.org.uk/pythoncode.txt that the site is suggesting over here: https://api.esd.org.uk/security

Comment: Their documentation is quite bad, to be frank, and that Python code is hardly complete. Note that their URL ends in a `?`, and doesn't account for other query parameters. It also doesn't handle URL encodings. I've looked at their PHP code and confirmed that they require hashing of the URL with URL encoding *decoded*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is missing the required `?` component before the `Application=` parameter. You probably want to add in a `&` if there are other parameters, however, and you need to remove the newline that `.encode("base64")` adds to the end of the value:

```
def sign_url(url, key, secret):
    sep = '&' if '?' in url else '?'
    url = '{}{}ApplicationKey={}'.format(url, sep, key)
    signature = hmac.new(secret, url, sha1).digest().encode("base64") 
    return '{}&Signature={}'.format(url, signature[:-1])
```

I note however that when the URL contains *URL-encoded elements* then the signature appears to be applied to the URL-decoded version (with `+` interpreted as spaces), so you really want to add a `urllib.unquote_plus()` (Python 2) / `urllib.parse.unquote_plus()` (Python 3) call when signing:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
except ImportError:
    from urlib import unquote_plus

def sign_url(url, key, secret):
    sep = '&' if '?' in url else '?'
    url = '{}{}ApplicationKey={}'.format(url, sep, key)
    signature = hmac.new(secret, unquote_plus(url), sha1).digest().encode("base64") 
    return '{}&Signature={}'.format(url, signature[:-1])
```

I've confirmed that this is what their [PHP example code](https://api.esd.org.uk/code.html) does and verified sample query parameters in the [online signature tool](https://developertools.esd.org.uk/service), e.g. when entering the path and parameters `foo%20bar?foo%20bar` into the tool, `CCuMYpCDznH4vIv95+NrN+RHEK0=` is produced as the signature, but using `foo+bar?foo+bar` produces the exact same signature even though `+` [should only be decoded as a space in form data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type).

I'd parse out the URL, add the `ApplicationKey` parameter to the parsed parameters, and then construct a new URL to sign.

Here's a version that does just that, and works both on Python 2 and on Python 3:

```
import hmac
import base64
from hashlib import sha1

try:
    # Python 3
    from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, unquote_plus, urlencode, urlparse
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl
    from urllib import unquote_plus, urlencode

def sign_url(url, key, secret):
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    query = parse_qsl(parsed.query)
    query.append(('ApplicationKey', key))
    to_sign = unquote_plus(parsed._replace(query=urlencode(query)).geturl())

    if not isinstance(secret, bytes):
        secret = secret.encode()
    if not isinstance(to_sign, bytes):
        to_sign = to_sign.encode()
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, to_sign, sha1).digest())
    if not isinstance(signature, str):
        signature = signature.decode()

    query.append(('Signature', signature))
    return parsed._replace(query=urlencode(query)).geturl()
```